# How to find the symmetric key algorithm being used for a TLS connection in Wireshark?

Tags: ssl, https, tcp, wireshark

I'm doing a TLS Wireshark lab and I can't find any information in Wireshark, the lab, or online how to find this answer:

*What symmetric key cryptography algorithm is being used by the client and server to encrypt  application data (in this case, HTTP messages)?*

How do I find the symmetric key algorithm being used for this TLS connection in Wireshark?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: wireshark-screenshot1]

[image: wireshark-screenshot2]

Comment: **The ciphersuite in the ServerHello message tells you** several things: in 1.2 and below it tells you the keyexchange-plus-authentication method, symmetric cipher and (if applicable) HMAC hash, and only in 1.2 for some suites, the KDF hash (called PRF); in 1.3 it skips kx/auth and tells you the symmetric cipher (which always _includes_ the MAC), and the KDF hash. ServerHello should be about 2-4 messages before the ones you showed.